# Is there a function or a way to sort strtotime dates by order and convert it back to readable date?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, strtotime

I have this array of dates already converted into strtotime:

```
Array ( [0] => 1481760000 [1] => 1482192000 [2] => 1478476800 [3] => 1482019200 )
```

Is there a function to sort/order this array into descending order and then convert it back to readable date format again?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php << great place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) with [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

```
sort($arrayOfTimestamps);
$arrayOfTimestamps = array_reverse($arrayOfTimestamps);

$arrayOfReadableDates = array();

foreach($arrayOfTimestamps as $timestamp) {
    $arrayOfReadableDates[] = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one.

```
$arr = Array ( [0] => 1481760000, [1] => 1482192000, [2] => 1478476800, [3] => 1482019200 );

asort($arr); //     low to high
or 
arsort($arr); //    high to low

foreach ($arr as $key =>$val) { 
     $arr[$key] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $val); // 'Y-m-d H:i:s' - update what date format you want

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo here.](https://eval.in/683296)

```
<?php
$array =array ( 1481760000, 1482192000, 1478476800, 1482019200 ) ;
usort($array, function($a, $b){return $b - $a;});
$array = array_map( function($item){return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $item);}, $array);
echo json_encode($array);
```